# 'Create Public Link' Apex OR SOQL code to retrieve this permission for current user profile

Tags: public-link-sharing

Starting Winter '19, There is a PermissionSet (and Profile System Setting) named 'Create Public Links' in Setup

What's the equivalent Apex or SOQL to read whether the current user profile id has access to 'Create Public Links' permission?

For example, this permission name in this SOQL throws error:

```
select Id, Name, PermissionCreatePublicLink From Profile Where Name='System Administrator'
```

or

```
select Id, Name, PermissionCreatePublicLink From PermissionSet Where Name='System Administrator'
```

I searched through all the permission fields available in these two objects, for Create Public Links

```
Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> schemaFieldMap = Schema.SObjectType.Profile.fields.getMap();
for (String fieldName: schemaFieldMap.keySet()) {
    System.debug('Field: ' + fieldName);
}

Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> schemaFieldMap = Schema.SObjectType.PermissionSet.fields.getMap();
for (String fieldName: schemaFieldMap.keySet()) {
    System.debug('Field: ' + fieldName);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The permission is actually called `ChatterFileLink`, so the field name is `PermissionsChatterFileLink`. It can sometimes be hard to track down the name of a permission, but there's actually a little trick I like to use. Go to a profile or permission set, find the permission you want, and hover over the checkbox for the permission. It will display the API name (e.g. `ChatterFileLink`). From there, most permissions actually start with `Permissions` followed by the name, which is how I arrived at the final answer.

[image: Hover Over Permission Checkbox To See API Name]

---

As far as finding out if the current user has permission?

```
Boolean userCanCreatePublicLinks = 0 <
  [SELECT COUNT() FROM PermissionSetAssignment 
   WHERE PermissionSet.PermissionsChatterFileLink = TRUE
     AND AssigneeId = :UserInfo.getUserId()];
```

This returns true if the user has the permission on their profile *or* any permission set.

Comment: "+1" for the hover over checkbox in Permission Sets to find the API name suffix.